# Adding viewport metatag breaks my template layout

Tags: templates, layout, google, mobile-detection

I have separate templates for desktop/tablet and phone.

I don't feel that viewport meta is needed in my mobile template, but without it Google is saying:

> Error: The page is not mobile friendly

However, when I add the standard tag, it actually screws up my template:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Is there a way to add the viewport to make Google (and Bing) happy and NOT mess with my layout?

The site in question is: https://www.hawkeye.ca

([cross-posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63853457/2943403))

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for posting your question here.  Please take our [tour] and consider telling us about you and your Joomla journey by editing your profile.  Please continue to research and toil your issue -- if you manage to self-solve, please post an educational answer for the benefit of future researchers.